# Training Random Forest in XGBoost 4J Spark

Tags: apache-spark, random-forest, xgboost

How to pass the num_parallel_tree param while training a random forest using XGBoost Spark 4J ?

I did the following after referring to [Random Forests in XGBoost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/rf.html)

```
    val hyperParams = Map(
       "booster" -> "gbtree",
        "objective" -> "binary:logistic", 
        "evalMetric" -> "logloss",
        "num_parallel_tree" -> 100)

    val xGBoostClassifier = new XGBoostClassifier(hyperParams)
      .setFeaturesCol(vectorAssembler.getOutputCol)
      .setLabelCol(labelColumnName)
      .setNumRound(1)
```

But the final model has only one tree. Looks like the `num_parallel_tree` parameter is not being used at all.
Even the logs of the XGBoost library which prints all the hyperparameters being used, doesn’t print the `num_parallel_tree`.

We are using the XGBoost version 1.0.0 with spark 2.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

The final model is 1 tree. It's complicated stuff in reality but you merge the different trees to a final tree. The whole point is to train different trees and somehow derive a final better such tree.

See https://www.knime.com/blog/from-a-single-decision-tree-to-a-random-forest